# How to use directory names as options or parameters?

Tags: php, apache, web

I don't even know how this method is called, I just know the behavior I want to achieve.

My example for this is Facebook. If you go to `facebook.com/[username or id]` you get to the profile page, but I can't imagine that they're creating a directory in their root folder and putting a index file in there for every user.

So how's the following behavior accomplished; You go to *`somepage.com/foo/bar/hello`* but actually you're requesting *`somepage.com/foo?bar=hello`* ?

Is this even possible with Apache and PHP?

Comment: Yes, look at `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` files for Apache

Comment: That thing is called an URL. Even if it can map onto directories, it must not. How the URL is processed is entirely hidden by the webserver that is recieving it. Nowhere in the HTTP standards is it said that there must be some kind of directory structure behind it.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 and http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 are often good to understand to do real work with URL rewriting and interacting with your webserver and the webbrowser from a PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't even know how this method is called, I just know the behavior I want to achieve.

That thing is called URI/URL and the local part of it is passed to a webserver. The webserver then processes the request.

> Is this even possible with Apache and PHP?

Yes. Not even even. This is what a webserver is for. What happens on the server is entirely shielded by the HTTP protocol which knows only the URI/URL specification which does not regulate if and how that needs to match to concrete processes or files on the webserver.

For example with the Apache HTTP Server there is a famous module called [*Mod_Rewrite*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that does URL-Rewriting. Often in a fashion that the user with her browser does not take any notice of it.

Example configuration with a PHP file (Apache HTTPD):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In a PHP script you can obtain the URI/URL by making use of special variables like [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 1):

Commonly this is made with [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/). There you can make a "path" to a variable of a script.

E.g. http://example.com/user/1/edit could be translated with mod rewrite to http://example.com/index.php?function=edit&userid=1

Such a rule would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/user/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php=function=$2&userid=$1 [L]
```

The first line activated the rewrite module the second line has a regular expression which must match for rewrite the url *internally*. If you like you can also make that *externally* with an `[R]` modifier instad of the `[L]`.

Have a look to the whole [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to learn more.

The stuff in the breckets are so called flags which are also [well documentated](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.htm).

I hope that helps!